# Java try/catch block not outputting text when exception is caught

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I've been going through the Head First Java 2E book, which covers Java 5, and I'm running into an issue with exception handling that I don't understand. In the exceptional handling chapter, the book gives the following example as the correct way to use a try/catch block to catch a MidiUnavailableException.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MusicTest {

    public void play() {
        try {
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            System.out.println("Sequencer initialized...");
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Bummer...");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicTest mt = new MusicTest();
        mt.play();
   }

}
```

Without the try/catch block, the program fails to compile with a MidiUnavailableException. I would expect that with the code above, I would get the output:

```
Bummer...
```

instead, I get

```
Sequencer initialized...
```

Is this just a difference between Java 5 and Java 8 or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Why would you expect that? Why do you expect your program to throw exceptions?

Comment: When you get "Sequencer initialized..." this means that there is no exception thrown ... the line System.out.println("Sequencer initialized..."); is executed.

Comment: I understand that, but if I take the try block out then I get an exception. Perhaps I don't fully understand how exceptions work, but why would a try/catch block have any effect on whether an exception is thrown? Shouldn't it just catch one if it is thrown?

Comment: No, if you remove the `catch`, you do not have an exception. You have a compile error. This is very different: an exception is at runtime, when the program is running. A compiler error is before that, it is when the you are compiling your program, before running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to keep it short.

Try/catch block handles an exception IF there is one.

BUT on some cases, you HAVE to put a try/catch block in order to use a class that MAY throw an exception.

So in your case if you take it out, your code won't compile because it is asking for the try/catch block, that doesn't mean there will always be an exception.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Sequencer Class *may* throw an exception. That's why you have to add the try catch blocks. But it runs fine so no exceptions are thrown.

Try to remove your device and then run it. It probably will then throw the exception.

Comment: If I don't have the try/catch block then I do get an exception. My understanding of the try/catch block is that it is used to handle an exception which may be thrown, but its presence shouldn't have any bearing on whether an exception is thrown or not.

Comment: You are mixing up runtime exceptions and compilation errors. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Argyle compile time errors are not exceptions. Normally you only get Exception when you run the program.

Comment: @Argyle  the Sequencer class is probably defined as something like this:  ```public void sequencer throws MIDIException ``` Which means that every person that uses this Object must also specify the try catch blocks. Otherwise it won't run.